# jQuery document ready functions

Tags: jquery, document-ready, ready

what are the differences (if any) for the following jQuery document ready functions:

`$("document").ready(function() {});`  and  `$(function() {});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equivalent, the later is a shorthand form for the first.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(handler)
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> $(handler)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is brevity. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

> **jQuery( callback )**
>
> **This function behaves just like `$(document).ready()`**, in that it should be used to wrap other `$()` operations on your page that depend on the DOM being ready. While this function is, technically, chainable, there really isn't much use for chaining against it.

<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. Check out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Answer (score 0):

They're the same; as stated earlier, the latter is merely a shorthand version of the former.

I prefer using the expanded version, as I feel it makes code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

`$(afunc)` just calls `$(document).ready(afunc);` after 4 if statements which don't get entered since afunc is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same. Different names to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
$().ready(function(){}) (this is not recommended)
$(function(){})
```