# equivalent ready functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Are these three equivalent?

```
$(function(){
  $("#a").html("i am a")
});
```

```
(function($){
  $("#b").html("i am b")
})($);
```

```
(function(){
  $("#c").html("i am c")
})();
```

[The code is available `here`.](http://jsfiddle.net/toeinriver/MPDKp/)

Reference:

- [jQuery document ready functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479817/jquery-document-ready-functions)

Comment: Btw, the recommended variant is `jQuery(function ($) { ... });`. So, even if a third-party script takes over the global `$` name, you can safely use it in your ready-handler.

Comment: Thanks, Sime! And why the variant works? How $ is assigned to jQuery inside the scope of jQuery()?

Comment: The `jQuery` function does that itself. It assigns *itself* as the to the first argument of the function that *it* received as *its* first argument (the ready-handler). So, just invoke the `jQuery` function, pass it a callback function (the ready-handler), and the first argument of *that* function will be the `jQuery` function itself. You can give it any name, but `$` makes most sense, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one actually waits for the ready event, while the others do not.

The second one is used for aliasing JQuery, but is useless in the way it is used now. You pass `$`, which is received in the parameter `$`. This construct is usually used when another library is used that assigns a different value to `$`. In that case you can call `function($){...}(jQuery)`, to still have the `$` variable pointing to jQuery in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first one waits until the document is ready, the other two do not. They simply create a scope for the code to run in rather than running in the global scope.